# Is it safe/efficient to use File.Move over a network share?

Tags: c#, windows, networking, copy, share

I have a DocumentStore (posh term for a network share) and a database holding entries relating to documents copied into the store.
I am going to be using the autogenerated (int) ID of the database row for the filename and partitioned directory structure (e.g. ID=4433 would eventually be put into '\004\433\0000004433.xxx')

I obviously can't keep any sort of lock on the database whilst copying a file but I am not sure which is the better strategy to take:

a) Adding a row to the database to get the ID (presumably with an InProgress flag), copying the file to the destination and then updating the row again to clear the flag once the copy is successful.

b) Copying the file to a temporary filename at the root of the share; Once that has finished, insert the new row into the database to get the ID and calling a File.Move to move the temporary file to the correct destination. If the insert/move file was done in a transaction then any failure would mean the insert is rolled back and not seen by anyone else

(b) should be OK if it really is a Move rather than Copy/Delete but would this be safe to do?

Comment: Tilak/Zdravko: Copy/Delete would not work for scenario b since there would be a database transaction open - it needs to be (near) instantaneous. I need to be certain that the Move functionality (ie just change directory pointers) is still applicable even when called from a machine that does not hold the share.

Answer (score 0):

Move is perfectly safe. It is not much different than Copy/Delete when going to a network share.

Answer (score 0):

Move is as safe as Copy/Delete.

Move does not delete from the source if source and destination are on different volume. Either it will copy or it will not copy.

```
Move = Copy if volume are different. (File.Delete is required to delete source file).  
Move = Copy + Delete is volume is same.
```

Other than above there is no difference using either Move/Move+Delete or Copy + Delete.